# On integrals of products of Laguerre polynomials

Tags: special-functions, laguerre

Let $L_k$  be the classical Laguerre polynomial with degree $k$ defined by
$$
L_k(x)=\left(\frac {d}{dx}-1\right)^{k}\bigl\{\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\bigr\}.
$$
Let me define for $a_1, a_2$ positive, $\alpha_1, \alpha_2\in \mathbb N$,
$$
K_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2}(a_1, a_2)=\iint_{t_1\ge 0, t_2\ge 0\\\frac{t_1}{a_1}+\frac{t_2}{a_2}\ge 1}
e^{-t_1-t_2}(-1)^{\alpha_1}L_{\alpha_1}(2t_1)(-1)^{\alpha_2}L_{\alpha_2}(2t_2)dt_1 dt_2.
$$
I would like to prove that $K_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2}(a_1, a_2)\ge 0$.

I know a (not-so-simple) proof of that inequality when $\min(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)=0$, but other cases remain open. Obviously there is a $n$-dimensional question by defining $K_{\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n}(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ and I know a proof for $n=1$, but not for $n\ge 2$ for general $\alpha$.